# Remove launchpad

Tags: macos, launchpad

I'm using alfred so no need in launchpad.

Is it safe to delete launchpad, any applications that depends from it?

How i can remove launchpad? Maybe AppCleaner application can help?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you remove LaunchPad ?

Comment: dont like to have unused staff.

Comment: Bc Spotlight keeps trying to make me open it instead of Launchbar

Comment: @patrix how come that my question (asked in 2013) is a duplicate of question asked in 2014?

Comment: Uhh, has been a while but from looking at both the newer question already had collected some good answers before the duplication was detected, so we probably wanted to keep the more active question open. But I agree that the notice is kind of misleading in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[An answer to a more recent question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145675/8546) (about Mavericks) shows the operating system guarding against modification or deletion of Launchpad. Finder presents an alert.

Removal of Launchpad.app from OS X 10.9.5 does not remove Launchpad functionality. The following screenshots demonstrate Launchpad without Launchpad.app loading then presenting apps:

[image: Screenshot of Launchpad loading applications without Launchpad.app]

[image: Screenshot of applications in Launchpad without Launchpad.app]

At least one core service includes references to `/Applications/Launchpad.app` so I should recommend **not attempting to remove** Launchpad.app or related software.