# Weird bar in the bottom-left. What is that?

Tags: macos, text-editor

Sometimes, when I hit a combination of keys (I have not figured out which one) a weird bar in the bottom-left of a screen appears. I cannot get rid of it in any way. The screencast: https://youtu.be/CdXVgth_sTk

The only way I have figured out of removing it is via: `killall Dock`.

What is the bar in question? How do you trigger it, how do you get rid of it, how to use it?

Comment: Does that appear when you aren’t using sublime text?

Comment: That was my guess @dwightk - quit sublime text or try a different text editor to be sure it’s not just a feature in that app. Maybe someone that knows ST can just answer if they know the setting to control / invoke that text input field / display.

Comment: It is not Sublime Text. When I quit literarily every app it still appears. Killing the 'Dock' process helps. It is weird in a sense that if, say in Chrome I type "map" and press enter quickly it will open built-in maps (same as presented in a video). My wild guess is some compact spotlight, but I have no clue how to use it nor how to exit out of it.

Comment: I have tried esc key, cmd+tab, cmd+q, cmd+w, looking for a weird process. Nothing. Is it some undocumented, wild, built-in Dock feature?

Comment: I can confirm that killing the Dock does _not_ kill Spotlight.

Comment: I should also note that the bar is not visible all the time. Sometimes it's invisible, but still opens random apps. Also, when it all happens my clipboard is all messed up. cmd+c copies after second/third attempt and sometimes pastes some gibberish that is a combination of previous copied texts. I thought it could be CopyClip's fault, but after closing it issues still happen until i `killall Dock` :/

Comment: It happened again today. What I've noticed is that whatever I type in the system appears in the Launchpad. Typing anything in Launchpad makes all the letters double. https://youtu.be/hjg9RI_tOzo Still, `killall Dock` fixes this. Is there a f* shortcut I press mistakenly that makes this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Use QuickTime to record your screen with the MacOS onscreen keyboard visible and you'll be able to figure out what key combo causes this to appear. Then you can track it down to a particular package.

Comment: It happens like once a month. I won't have QT running in the background all the time ><

Comment: @DCzajkowski your first priority is to be able to reproduce it on demand

Comment: I have found the issue of randomly opening apps, but I still don't know what is triggering that. Here's a link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjg9RI_tOzo

Comment: Does it happen in a guest account?

Comment: I have never used a guest account nor can I reproduce the issue on demand. It happens sometimes, it breaks cmd+c/cmd+v, and the bar below appears also sometimes. `killall Dock` fixes it.

Comment: The point is to use a guest account to figure out whether the problem is confined to your user account only, or globally to MacOS.

Comment: I get that, but if it appears every one month or so, and is triggered by mistake by pressing some random, weird keyboard shortcut, don't expect me to use the guest account for one month or so 

Comment: How about disabling Launchpad and see if the issue still happens? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145671/how-can-i-remove-the-launchpad